# pandas dataframe.equals why not first checking equal shapes?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Am reading a large set of data into pandas dataframe
Before processing further I need to look for any duplicates

I use itertools.permutations(dfs, r=2) to create all possible permutations of 2 elements
Then on each pairs I thought that using df1.equals(df2) would be quick enough

However with large number of dataframes (size of individual dataframes has less impact), the comparison becomes extremely slow.
Number of permutations is: n! / (n-r)!, so with 500 dataframes => 500*499 ~ 250000 permutations, so yes it grows very quickly

I was a bit surprised by the performance so I investigated a bit and found that doing df1.shape()==df2.shape() and only if this is true check df1.equals(df2) speeds up the comparison a lot.

I am really surprised as I thought this would be the first test done by df1.equals(df2) but this shows it is not
So my question is anyone knows what df1.equals(df2) is doing and why is it not first comparing the shapes?

This is desription of pandas.equals function:

> Test whether two objects contain the same elements.
>
> This function allows two Series or DataFrames to be compared against each other **to see if they have the same shape and elements**. NaNs in the same location are considered equal.
>
> The row/column index do not need to have the same type, as long as the values are considered equal. Corresponding columns must be of the same dtype.

So I cannot see any case where comparing shapes first would generate incorrect True/False result, anyone who has an example where this would fail?

Code example with 2 versions of comparison:
On my machine I get:
V1 : 2.4
V2 : 1.3
On my real dataset the impact is larger than 50% speed up

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import itertools
import time
import random


def flag_duplicate_v1(dfs) -> None:
    for pairs in itertools.permutations(dfs.keys(), r=2):
        df1 = dfs[pairs[0]]
        df2 = dfs[pairs[1]]
        if type(df1) == str or type(df2) == str:
            # df1 or df2 has been marked duplicate in this loop, skip
            # comparing to remaining non-duplicate is enough
            continue

        if df1.equals(df2):
            print(f"df1 {pairs[0]} and df2 {pairs[1]} are duplicates")
            dfs[pairs[1]] = "DUPLICATE"
    return dfs


def flag_duplicate_v2(dfs) -> None:
    for pairs in itertools.permutations(dfs.keys(), r=2):
        df1 = dfs[pairs[0]]
        df2 = dfs[pairs[1]]
        if type(df1) == str or type(df2) == str:
            # df1 or df2 has been marked duplicate in this loop, skip
            # comparing to remaining non-duplicate is enough
            continue

        if df1.shape == df2.shape:
            if df1.equals(df2):
                print(f"df1 {pairs[0]} and df2 {pairs[1]} are duplicates")
                dfs[pairs[1]] = "DUPLICATE"
        # else not same shape so not duplicates
    return dfs


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # create number_df random dataframes
    dfs = {}
    number_df = 500
    for i in range(number_df):
        length = random.randint(1, 10)
        df = pd.DataFrame(
            {
                "A": np.random.randn(length),
                "B": np.random.randint(2, 10, length),
                "C": [
                    np.random.choice(["rand_1", "rand_2", "rand_4", "rand_6"])
                    for i in range(length)
                ],
            }
        )
        dfs[i] = df
    # add a duplicate
    dfs[number_df] = dfs[random.randint(1, number_df - 1)]

    tic_full_process = time.perf_counter()
    dfs_with_duplicates_v1 = flag_duplicate_v1(dfs)
    print(f"V1 : {time.perf_counter() - tic_full_process:0.1f}")

    tic_full_process = time.perf_counter()
    dfs_with_duplicates_v2 = flag_duplicate_v2(dfs)
    print(f"V2 : {time.perf_counter() - tic_full_process:0.1f}")

    if dfs_with_duplicates_v1 == dfs_with_duplicates_v2:
        print("SAME RESULT")
    else:
        print("DIFFERENT RESULT")
```

Comment: No idea why that is, but it's a performance issue interesting to check. I've opened an issue in the pandas github for them to check it, here's the [link](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/53945)